# Syntax error compiling header containing "char[]"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to build a Visual C++ 2008 DLL using SDL_Mixer 1.2:

http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/

This is supposedly from a build made for Visual C++, but when I include SDL_mixer.h I get error **C2143**: "**syntax error : missing ';' before '['**".

The problem line is:

const char[] MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED = "MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED";

Is this because of the use of the dynamic array construct "char[]", instead of "char*"?

All the expressions in the file are wrapped by "`extern "C" {`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.  Although the answers here are correct regarding C construct, the actual problem was that I had included a "D" language file instead of the C version.

Answer (score 5):

move the square brackets after the variable name

```
const char MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED[] = "MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED";
```

Comment: Weird that it was the way it was, since this is presumably a package that others use, and the language type is definitely defined as "C".

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
const char MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED[] = "MIX_EFFECTSMAXSPEED";
```

Note that there is no "dynamic array construct" here - you have an array of char that is initialised witha string literal - all compile time things.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll have to change the distribution header.  Yuch.